# key shortcuts containing the key of CTRL not work in Rstudio for Mac

Tags: macos, rstudio

I just began to use Rstudio for Mac. However, I discoverd that I can't use most key shortcuts that containing the key of Control in Rstudio for Mac, such as CTRL+1, CTRL+2, CTRL+F1 etc. But CTRL+L seems worked.

The information of my Rstudio verison:
OS Version      : 10.11.3
RStudio Version : 1.1.383
R Version       : 3.4.3

Comment: In Mac, shortcuts are used with `cmd` key.

Comment: Thanks. I had solved the problem. Because a chinese input's key shortcut conflicts with the Rstudio.